# Rails service objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, stripe-payments, service-object

I'm using service objects to abstract a stripe payment feature into it's own class. I'm using this method https://gist.github.com/ryanb/4172391 talked about by ryan bates.

```
class Purchase
  def initialize(order)
    @order = order
  end

  def create_customer
    customer = stipe create customer
    if customer
       charge_customer(customer)
    else
       stipe error in creating customer
    end
  end

  def charge_customer(customer)
      if charge is sucessfull
         update_order(charge details)
      else
         stripe error in charging card
      end     
  end
  def update_order
     @order.update(payment attributes)
  end
end
```

Then in the order controller i'm doing something like

```
def create
@order = Order.new(params[:order])
 if @order.save
    payment = Payment.new(@order)
 else 
   render 'new' with flash message "payment error"
 end
end
```

My question is, how do i get the stipe error messages("stipe error in creating customer" and "stripe error in charging card") to display to the user?
Or can i call a service object in the order model and add it to order error messages? For example,
Order controller

```
@order.save_with_payment
```

Order model

```
def save_with_payement
   payment = Payment.new(self)
   #update order 
   self.payment_token = payment.token
   etc
end
```

If i can do that with the model, how to i make a validation that shows the stripe errors?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

First of all try to separate concerns as possible. It already feels like Your Purchase/Payment class is doing too much, probably it should delegate part of it's routines to other service objects.

Second, I agree with phoet. I don't see the reason why You wouldn't pass params hash to service object. In our latest project we fully rely on service objects we call Factories to produce/manipulate our model objects. In Your case You could do like this:

```
class OrderFactory
  def self.create(params)
    new(params).create
  end

  def initialize(params)
    @order = Order.new(params[:order])
  end

  def create
    @payment = Payment.new(self)
    @order.payment_token = payment.token
    #....
  end
end
```

Talking about validations - You can add validation methods to plain Ruby objects. For example by using ActiveModel: 
http://yehudakatz.com/2010/01/10/activemodel-make-any-ruby-object-feel-like-activerecord/
Then You can create custom validators, [like Ryan suggested](http://railscasts.com/episodes/211-validations-in-rails-3).

Or You can use a gem like [Virtus](https://github.com/solnic/virtus) and add some custom validation rules.

Comment: The params prob. is because a lot of what's in the params are protected attrs and need to be checked with other model values before manually updating them but thanks, i'll have a look at those links and try them now.

Comment: It does not contradict to what I have posted already. You can create a method on Your Order model to do this custom assignment logic. Or encapsulate this logic inside another method in OrderFactory or even separate object.

Answer (score 0):

i think that the service should be responsible for handling all this. so it might look like this

```
def create
  @payment = Payment.new(params[:order])
  if @order = @payment.execute_transaction
    [...]
  else 
    [...]
  end
end
```

so the payment service would handle creating and persisting the order and also might be adding validation errors. you could also return some kind of `@result` object that might consist of the order and depending error messages.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer, the only problem is that i have a lot of protected attributes in that params[:order] that'll be set manually and validated eg using product_id to get the product and checking if the product equalse amount in params[:order] and set the amount to be charged from the product found with the product id as anyone can easily bypass the javascript amount validation. Is there a way to set protected attributes from the payment class?

Comment: you will have to refactor your class to make it work with such a service.

Comment: I think if you use strong parameters instead of attr_accesible etc., you can have the controller only pass permitted params to the service object; otherwise params errors can stop processing before it ever gets there.

Comment: Oh i see, so that's what strong parameters do. I'm still on rails 3 unfourtunately, are there ways to replicate stuff like that in rails 3?

Answer (score 0):

I asked a very similar question just one day ago. The response I received was very helpful indeed (credit to @gary-s-weaver) so take a look.

[Rails generic errors array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19258343/rails-generic-errors-array)

I went with the rescue_from approach in the end and it works well for me. Let me know how you get on as I'm very interested in this area. And if you need any code samples give me a shout.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a gem for service objects. Check out [peafowl](https://github.com/AliSepehri/peafowl) gem.